# React Animation of menuItem in MenuBar does not work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, framer-motion

I'm using react and typescript.
The animation is done using framer-motion.
When the button is pressed, the menubar opens. frame-motion animation is implemented in the menuItem, but the menuItem is not moving.

I made it myself.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-elion-lgpnh?file=/src/App.tsx

Refarence site
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-side-menu-mx2rw?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FExample.tsx

Answer (score 1):

You need to inform the children that the animation changed from open to closed or vice-versa upon the menu button click.

With little modifications, I made it work for staggering the menu items upon menu open. You can check the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-platform-oc11f?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Also notice that I added a `transition-delay` before hiding the menu. This is to ensure that menu items stagger out of the screen first